# Multiple Select but Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datagridview, multiple-select

I'm still newbie about this.. i'm trying to make multiple select in condition if the selected rows contains string that I wanted, I've already get the value, but when I tried to get the same value in another rows, it throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object, what I'm trying to do is, if I've already get the selected rows that I need, I want to clear the cells, not remove the rows. I'm using right click event, that I found in some case in stackoverflow. hope you can understanding, thanks for your help and explanation... here is my code

if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

```
            rw = dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;


            cellValueNota = (int)dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows[rw].Cells[5].Value;
            String cl = Convert.ToString(cellValueNota);


            dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows[rw].Selected = true;

            ContextMenuStrip m = new ContextMenuStrip();

            m.Items.Add("Cancel");
            m.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(m_ItemClicked);
            m.Show(dgv_Jadwal_Sewa, new Point(e.X, e.Y));


    } 



  public void cancel_Booking()
        {
                String cl = Convert.ToString(cellValueNota);


                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().ToString().Contains(cl))
                    {
                        rw = row.Index;
                        //row.Selected = true;
                        dgv_Jadwal_Sewa.Rows[rw].Selected = true;


                        break;
                    }
                }




        }
```

it's throw on this line `(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().ToString().Contains(cl))`

Comment: Are you completely sure you have 6 objects in Cells? Or if Cells is not null? Debug it. Remove double ToString() :D

Comment: yes I'm sure have 6 objects, I've remove the double toString() but still throw the same when I click menu Context menu Cancel...

Comment: Which field is null? If you use VS debugger you can check it by hovering variables in text editor

Comment: no field is null,, I've chose the cell was not null. I'm try to select automatically when the context menu is clicked if in rows have same value in what clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row.Cells[5] is null or row.Cells[5].Value is null or row is null.